# swfupload ie9 error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, fancybox, swfupload

I'm using swfupload into fancybox window. i m coding php.

my code:

```
    var upload1, upload2;


        upload1 = new SWFUpload({
            // Backend Settings
            upload_url: "_upload.php",
            post_params: {
                "PHPSESSID" : "<?php echo session_id(); ?>",
                "sayfa":"YeniYazi",
                "nereye":"Downloads"
            },

            // File Upload Settings
            file_size_limit : "102400", // 100MB
            file_types : "*.*",
            file_types_description : "All Files",
            file_upload_limit : "102400",
            file_queue_limit : "0",

            // Event Handler Settings (all my handlers are in the Handler.js file)
            file_dialog_start_handler : fileDialogStart,
            file_queued_handler : fileQueued,
            file_queue_error_handler : fileQueueError,
            file_dialog_complete_handler : fileDialogComplete,
            upload_start_handler : uploadStart,
            upload_progress_handler : uploadProgress,
            upload_error_handler : uploadError,
            upload_success_handler : uploadSuccess,
            upload_complete_handler : uploadComplete,

            // Button Settings
            button_image_url : "images/XPButtonUploadText_61x22.png",
            button_placeholder_id : "spanButtonPlaceholder1",
            button_width: 61,
            button_height: 22,

            // Flash Settings
            **flash_url : "swfupload/swfupload.swf",**


            custom_settings : {
                progressTarget : "fsUploadProgress1",
                cancelButtonId : "btnCancel1"
            },

            // Debug Settings
            debug: false
        });
```

my problem is with swfupload. it's run ie 8,  when i upgrade ie8 to ie9 starting this problem.

when i remove **flash_url : "swfupload/swfupload.swf",** code, works for me.

i can't upload image sorry.

help me.

Comment: was an improvement regarding this issue.

reason for this error swfupload is null reference exception. 
how I die swfupload when fancybox close or destory swfupload.

Comment: So what's your question?  What do you need help with?  From what you wrote, the change you made fixed the problem.